# Styling the webform contact autocomplete box

Tags: webform-civicrm

I've been working on a site using bootstrap which has a dark background and white text. This seems to be causing some problems for the webform contact autocomplete box where the default background is white, but is presumably picking up the white body text also.

Could anyone point to the CSS file which styles the autocomplete box?

Many thanks!

[image: Example of form element with unreadable text]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone's looking for it in future, it's found in

> sites/all/modules/webform_civicrm/css/token-input.css